# Bootbox: how to add a 'prompt'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, flask, prompt, bootbox

would you be so kind to enlighten me; i have the following issue

in **jcertify.html** there is :

```
<!-- Bootbox utilities 
    ================================================== -->
    <script src"../static/assets/js/email_sign_up.js"></script>
  </body>
```

in **email_sign_up.js** there is :

```
function    emailSignUp( )
{
    bootbox.prompt("<strong>Email address</strong>Enter email address where the report should be send to : ", function(result)  {                
        if (result) {   
            // Example.show("email: <b>"+result+"</b>");    
            console.log("NikoS");
        } 
    });
}
```

in **jcertify.html** it is like :

```
<p><a href="javascript:console.log('hi there');emailSignUp();" class="bb-trigger btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign up</a></p>
```

in the browser's debugger, when i click on the "Sign up" button what i see is :

***[Log] hi there (jcertify, line 1)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: emailSignUp
    global code (jcertify, line 1)***

do you have any idea what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you check that email_sign_up.js is successfully being loaded by the browser?

Comment: is not loaded? why so, since it is referenced?

Comment: Well there are a number of reasons. Maybe the path you had is actually incorrect. Maybe there's a javascript error at the start of the file before the function declaration. It's really hard to debug for sure. In the browser's console you could try typing in emailSignUp() and see if that works.

Comment: the email_sign_up.js contains only the function described above. the path for sure is correct.

Comment: if i put the function in the body of the html, i am getting :

Comment: [Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'b(n.form)')
 prompt (bootbox.min.js, line 6)
 emailSignUp (jcertify, line 138)
 global code (jcertify, line 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()    {

    $(document).on("click", "#signin_session", function(event)  {
        event.preventDefault() ;

        bootbox.prompt("<strong>Email address</strong><br>Please enter the email address where the report should be send to : ", function(email_address)  {
                if (email_address)  { 

                    formulate           = {'email_address': email_address} ;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:            "/jcertify/session-report/",
                        data:           JSON.stringify(formulate,null), // {'email_address': email_address},
                        type:           "POST",
                        contentType:    "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                        success:        function(response) { document.write(response) ; },
                        error:          function(error) { console.log(error) ; }
                    });

                }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/f75nfL26/1/

HTML:

```
<a class="bb-trigger btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign up</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.bb-trigger').on("click", function(e) {
bootbox.prompt("<strong>Email address</strong>Enter email address where the report should be send to : ", function(result)  {                
    if (result) {   
        // Example.show("email: <b>"+result+"</b>");    
        console.log("NikoS");
    } 
});
```

});

Working fine there